# ParHashMap.map method with function call

Tags: scala

How can I use the parallel `ParHashMap.map` to when I want to apply a function to each of the elements in the `ParHashMap`?

Here is a complete example. The call to the map-function never returns:

```
import scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParHashMap
object parTest extends Application {

   def foo(a: Any) = .1
   val U = ParHashMap[String, Double](("test",1))
   println(U)

   val V = U.map( entry => foo(entry) )
   println(V)
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `App` rather than `Application` (which is deprecated). I tested it with App and it works fine.